# Why are $(X_1), (X_1,X_2), \ldots$ prime ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra

I was looking at the proof of the dimension of the polynomial ring $R[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ and I had a question: Why are $(X_1), (X_1,X_2), (X_1,X_2,X_3),\ldots, (X_1,\ldots,X_n)$  prime ideals in this ring? I couldn't even prove that they are ideals, I really need help.

**EDIT**

My problem is I don't understand why if $f,g\in R[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ such that $fg+I=I\implies f$ or $g\in I$, where $I=(X_1)$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The parentheses around them indicate the *ideal generated by those things*, so they form an ideal by definition.

Secondly, you can tell they are prime by looking at the quotient ring by each ideal. You believe polynomial rings over fields are domains, right?

Comment: Right, but I couldn't prove it neither, it gives me the same problem: Why does if $f,g\in R[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ such that $fg\in (X_1)$ imply $f$ or $g\in (X)$?

Comment: @user42912 it doesn't sound like you actually tried my suggestion. Do you believe that polynomial rings over fields are domains? Do you believe that R/I is a domain iff I is a prime ideal?

Comment: yes, $R[X_1,\ldots, X_n]$ is domain, but what we have to prove is $R[X_1,\ldots, X_n]/I$ is domain.

Comment: @user42912 Sure, but look: $R[X_1,\ldots,X_n]/(X_1)\cong R[x_2,\ldots,x_n]$! Do you see what I'm getting at now? :)

Comment: yes, I had noticed that, that's what I'm trying to solve right now :)

Comment: I mean, I'm trying to prove this isomorphism, to do that I'm trying to find an epimorphism such that $(x_1)$ is kernel, any guess?

Comment: @user42912 for each polynomial, map the polynomial to the result of substituting 0 for $X_1$. Show that's the map you seek

Comment: yes, I've already done this, thanks